# Randomly select one Date from each month for 12 months in a year, excluding Saturdays and Sundays

Tags: oracle, t-sql, date, random

How can I select one random date in a month for 12 months in a year excluding Saturdays and Sundays? (Finally I should have 12 dates 1 from each month).  I need it for both T-SQL and Oracle. Please help me.

Comment: What is your query/have you written anything?

Comment: When you say "year" do you mean calendar year (Jan 2017 - Dec 2017) or last twelve months (Jul 2017 - Jun 2018)?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly. We are not here to write your code for you, we are here to help you solve specific problems in your code. For this, we need to see what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
**for oracle**

```
with tst as (
  Select level as mnth 
  from dual connect by level <= 12
)
select to_date(floor(DBMS_Random.Value(1,to_char(last_day(to_date(mnth, 'mm')), 'dd')))||'-'||mnth, 'dd-mm') dt 
from tst

with tst as (
  Select level as mnth from dual connect by level <= 12
)
select to_date(floor(DBMS_Random.Value(1,to_char(last_day(to_date(mnth||'-'||2017, 'mm-yyyy')), 'dd')))||'-'||mnth||'-'||2017, 'dd-mm-yyyy') t from tst
```

Query 1 - for current year
Query 2 - for specified year

for t-sql you can try with this query by changing correct function instead of to_date, to_char, random

Comment: Thank you very much Gaj for your script. It's working fine and brings in one random date from each month in a calendar year. Can you please suggest how to modify it to get it for the last 12 months. (Jul 2017 - Jun 2018)